# How to stop icon tooltips in bullseye

Tags: raspbian

I have a problem with my raspberry 4 using latest raspian (Bullseye), on a touch screen.  When I click a desktop icon for eg; netflix, a pop up name 'netflix' shows and does not go away.  On a non-touch screen, this icon is shown when the mouse hovers over the icon, but on my touch screen, it stays there permanent. Now, maybe there is a mouse setting to stop this, maybe there is a way of not showing this icon at all.  I was hoping there might be a desktop shortcut command I could use that stops this happening or is it built into the the OS at a level I can not stop?  Any ideas?
I have tried many settings in LX desktop but there is nothing that solves this.  I have edited my /home/..../panel configuration to show 'tooltips ='.  But they are still there and always over the video.  Very irritating.

Answer (score 1):

The answer relates to tooltips:

Make a copy of this file: /home/pi/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel
and place it in: /etc/xdg/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels edit this file (or both, but I think this one is the key), search for tooltips and change from 1 to 0.

This method I found here: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=271916

Seems strange that taskbar tooltips settings relate to shutting off the name highlight when you hover over an desktop icon but a solution is a solution.